# Gradle 'Provided' dependency for Java plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I am attempting to compile several WAR files, all that depend on a common JAR module. In my Gradle build however, I cannot seem to get a 'Provided' like dependency to work with the Java plugin.

My compile looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
configurations{
    providedCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile module("org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:${springAmqpVersion}")
    compile module("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}")
    compile module("org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:${slf4jVersion}")

    providedCompile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:${servletApiVersion}"

    runtime module("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}")
    runtime module("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}")
    runtime module("org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}")

    sourceArchives module("org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:${springAmqpVersion}:sources")
    sourceArchives module("javax.servlet:servlet-api:${servletApiVersion}:sources")
}


sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile }
}
```

However, that last bit is where it gets an exception. I have tried adding the servlet-api (Provided by Tomcat) to the configuration after the runtime dependencies would extend it, or simply putting it in as a compile module, then removing it from runtime dependencies later.

I've attempted several different ways of modifying the dependencies, with my closest results being:

```
newRuntime = configurations.runtime.minus(configurations.providedCompile)
configurations.runtime = newRuntime
```

This last bit however, will generate the variable *newRuntime* with the proper dependencies, however when I tried to reassign the variable back to the runtime configuration, it throws a "Cannot find property exception"

I found a lot of discussion of this exact problem on Gradle's bug tracking:[Gradle-784](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784)

However the main lead from that is from Spring who uses Maven with their gradle builds, which I am unfamiliar with.

The most promising link I found here on SO, but unfortunately I could not get the examples to work as well: [SO Provided Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle)
Of note for the Stack Overflow question the line that showed most promise:

```
//Include provided for compilation
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
```

This line does not give an error like other attempts, however it appears that the providedCompile (My version of provided) dependency is not actually put on the compile classpath, as there is a classpath error when compilation is attempted.

Comment: Of note, http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_best_define_dependencies_as_provided seems to recommend just setting compile to extend the provided configuration. This appears to be working, but logically is not making sense as runtime also extends compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define a compile-time \*only\* classpath in Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% following your message but providedCompile is only allowed for 'war' plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
  // others go here
  providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${servletVersion}"
}
```

During 'war' step the servlet jar is not included.

Comment: That's the concept I'm going for actually. But to note I added a configuration for providedCompile without the war plugin. I'm attempting to get the same functionality in the Java JAR that a WAR would have. Some people have recommended using the WAR plugin, with jar.enabled on, then deleting the WAR. This is what we're currently doing, however the provided dependencies are in the JAR that is created afterwards.

Comment: I would say: do not fight the tool.

Answer (score 5):

You have added a `providedCompile` configuration, but you aren't doing anything with it. Hence it won't make it on any class path. To put the configuration on the main compile class path, you can do:

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
```

Likewise, to put it on the test compile class path:

```
sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
```

Comment: I tried this out, realizing that I did in fact forget to put it into Test, but I'm still getting:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Looking for that JAR file. 
Is there anything that I should know about the gradle solution that I found where it makes compile extend provided? That solution appears to be working, the JAR is not in the resulting WAR and all tests are compiling correctly.

Comment: Without more information, I can't say what the problem is. This solution works for me. If you just do `configurations.compile.extends configurations.provided`, I think the provided dependencies will end up in the War (without additional counter measures).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **compile** scope inside 'jar' modules and **providedCompile** inside 'war' module.

War's **providedCompile** scope will override jar's **compile** scope.