# Copy dependencies excluding some configuration

Tags: gradle

Suppose a project layout like this:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"

    configurations {
        provided
        compile.extendsFrom(provided)
    }
}

project("a") {
    dependencies {
        compile("foo:bar:1.0")
        ...
        provided("bar:baz:3.14")
        ...
    }
}

project("b") {
    dependencies {
        compile("abc:def:1.0")
        ...
        provided("xyz:foo:3.14")
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(":a"))
    compile(project(":b"))
}
```

Now, I need a task that will copy all the dependencies of root project (transitively) to some directory, but excluding the `provided` configuration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was a little obsessed with this and tried to figure out how to do it. I got it to work with the following gradle file. Note the configurations part and where I copy the dependencies.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"

    configurations {
        provided
    }

    sourceSets {
        main { 
            compileClasspath += configurations.provided 
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project("a") {
    dependencies {
        compile("jdom:jdom:1.0")
        provided("javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5")
    }
}

project("b") {
    dependencies {
        compile("javax.jcr:jcr:2.0")
        provided("commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(":a"))
    compile(project(":b"))
}

task copyDependencies(type:Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'build/dependencies'
}
```

I think it's a simpler solution to this problem, but did not figure it out. But this one works. The only thing is that you have to add provided configuration to idea/eclipse classpath too to make the ide integration work as espected.

Answer (score 8):

To copy only compile dependencies (that is not in the provided dependencies set) to a directory, this should work:

```
task copyDependencies(type:Copy) {
    from (configurations.compile - configurations.provided)
    into 'build/dependencies'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work - all the dependencies get copied. Probably because dependencies declared as `provided` are transitive to the root project.

Comment: It seems that the configurations.provided is empty when executing that task.

Comment: Not sure what changed from when this was posted, but this seems to work now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look also at [providedCompile without war plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925724/providedcompile-without-war-plugin) question.

There is notion of [SpringSource propdeps Gradle plugin](https://github.com/SpringSource/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin) featuring provided configuration support.