# "provided" scope not working - android studio with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I need to prevent gradle from exporting a certain shared library.

I´ve read that using the provided scope should do the trick, but it seems that it was only working with older gradle versions.

Is there any other way to exclude dependencies from the build process to not get them into the final apk?

Comment: what exact dependencies? are they really provided by Android platform?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle/24686771#24686771

Comment: Now I have a new project where it seems to work flawlessly, at least for the android support libraries I´m using

Answer (score 3):

I have found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406184/310760

But for Gradle 2.0 it has small changes:

```
configurations{
  provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided

idea {
  module{
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided] // for Gradle 2.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I found some solutions.But I don't understand.

http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

Comment: I've solved my problem by manually removing the library from the apk file. Clearly not the best solution but it worked for my case

Answer (score 0):

Solved thie problem by using the android-apt gradle plugin.

see https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/overview

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.ligboy.test.card.module1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    apt
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    apt 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    apt 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    apt 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: You don't need `android-apt` for that, in fact, you are overriding the `apt` scope here by using the `configurations` block.

Answer (score 0):

Fought with this for a while and found:

1. "provided" is part of gradle 1.3.0, but doesn't work properly.
2. "provided" works properly in gradle 1.5.0!

FYI:  I had to delete my build directory after upgrading to 1.5.0 to remove the lib file from the .aar.