# Is there a way to customize the scopes for android studio using gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently had to add a compile time only dependency for my Android project. Finally I figured out how to do that with gradle [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle/24686771#24686771) and my project compiles fine. But the compile time only dependency doesn't seem to be in Android Studio's classpath, hence Android Studio fails to resolve the class symbols and autocomplete doesn't work.

To be specific, Android Studio is not being able to parse this and add the required dependencies to its classpath:

```
libraryVariants.all {
    variant -> variant.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.providedlibs
}
```

In Intellij, you could do it this way by using the idea plugin:

```
idea {
  module{
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.providedlibs
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do that in Android Studio?

Even though its built on top of Intellij, the above doesn't work. I get the error: 
"Cannot get property 'plus' on null object"