# Gradle archive contains more than 65535 entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, hadoop, zip

I am integrating hadoop2.5.0 for running mapreduce job and spring-boot-1.2.7 release and getting error while including this

1. **Archive contains more than 65535 entries.**

My gradle jar dependency

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { 
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
    }
```

2. On including zip64 in jar - I am getting **invalid or corrupt file**.

```
jar {
    zip64=true
    from configurations.compile.collect { 
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
    }
```

3. On adding shadowJar

   shadowJar {
   zip64=true
   }

**I am getting error**

```
Unable to read bytes        
at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher
```

How should I make one jar out of all dependencies.

Comment: Spring Boot's executable jars don't support Zip64: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2895. Could you use one or more nested jars instead?

Comment: I want to combine all in single jar as I am facing issue of guava dependency which is older in hadoop jars while spring is using latest guava jars.I am having confict if I directly this jars due to guava versions adopted by both

Comment: do you have any examples of nesting ?,I will try it out

Comment: Spring Boot's Gradle plugin has a repackage task that will nest your dependencies inside the jar. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html. I'm not sure that it'll play nicely with Hadoop, though. Avoiding the use of Guava may be an easier solution.

Comment: @andy ,Thanks a lot solved the problem using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1310.I added hbase and hadoop as provided.I removed zip64 from jar{}

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in the comments, here is the relevant piece as provided by the asker themselves:

> Thanks a lot solved the problem using
> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/%E2%80%A6) and
> http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1310 I added
> hbase and hadoop as provided.I removed zip64 from jar{}

A quick glance suggests the key part from the SO answer is:

> currently the best solution is to declare your own `provided`
> configuration, that will included compile-only dependencies and add to
> to your compile classpath

The github seems to overlap with this, plus the key detail:

> I added the following in my jar task of all the sub projects and got
> my jars spared. `bootRepackage.enabled = false`