# Gradle distZip - adds excluded dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

My project uses

```
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
```

I added Google Sheets API to dependencies. Now
`gradle dependencies` says Google Sheets API uses `org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211` which I assume to exclude, because classes are loaded from the wrong jar:

```
compile (group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-sheets', version: 'v4-rev25-1.22.0') {
    exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
}
compile (group: 'com.google.gdata', name: 'core', version: '1.47.1') {
    exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
}
```

Now `gradle dependencies` does not show servlet-api:2.5 to be used anywhere. But after gradle clean distZip I see that archive contains `servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar`! How can I exclude it from the build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define a compile-time \*only\* classpath in Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405970/how-do-i-define-a-compile-time-only-classpath-in-gradle)

Comment: see xsveda's answer in the thread used to mark this as duplicate